# tkinter - wm_protocol dosent handle the WM_HELP message

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, tcl

Does tkinter just handle known protocols? If so, it seems useless to me. If not I'm not sure why this code dosent works for me under microsoft.

```
import tkinter as tk
def lol():
    print('hi')

root = tk.Tk()

menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = tk.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New")

root.wm_protocol('WM_HELP',lol)
root.mainloop()
```

As I understand [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/wm-help) a message should be sent by toggle *F1* and the window should [respond](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.html#M39) with the command to this protocol.

Comment: doesn't work for me either, however you can still `root.bind('<F1>', lambda e: lol())` if the f1 key is what you wanted (tho probably then you wouldn't ask this question)

Comment: @Matiiss in fact I'm looking for a different topic with more questions about it. This is just an *easy* example of the mechanic I dont understand. I surely would find a way around this, but it could be easier if some one could help me out here.

Comment: The only ones we really support are `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` and `_NET_WM_PING`, with the latter being hard-coded (because the script level can't handle it right and there's always one correct thing to do). Any other protocols… well, if they are simple one-way messages like `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` then they'll work. Otherwise they won't.

Comment: For details of why this is all the case, see the implementation at https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/50c34e54dc3e5a32c2c712809d133b23b99f5e12/unix/tkUnixWm.c#L6326

Comment: @Donal thanks for clarifying this issue. To close the case I would like to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## X11

Right at the bottom of the X11 implementation of Tk (the library under Tkinter) is [this code](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/50c34e54dc3e5a32c2c712809d133b23b99f5e12/unix/tkUnixWm.c#L6326), which I copy here without the comments:

```c
void
TkWmProtocolEventProc(
    TkWindow *winPtr,
    XEvent *eventPtr)
{
    WmInfo *wmPtr;
    ProtocolHandler *protPtr;
    Atom protocol;
    int result;
    const char *protocolName;
    Tcl_Interp *interp;

    protocol = (Atom) eventPtr->xclient.data.l[0];

    if (protocol == Tk_InternAtom((Tk_Window) winPtr, "_NET_WM_PING")) {
        Window root = XRootWindow(winPtr->display, winPtr->screenNum);

        eventPtr->xclient.window = root;
        (void) XSendEvent(winPtr->display, root, False,
                (SubstructureNotifyMask|SubstructureRedirectMask), eventPtr);
        return;
    }

    wmPtr = winPtr->wmInfoPtr;
    if (wmPtr == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    protocolName = Tk_GetAtomName((Tk_Window) winPtr, protocol);
    for (protPtr = wmPtr->protPtr; protPtr != NULL;
            protPtr = protPtr->nextPtr) {
        if (protocol == protPtr->protocol) {
            Tcl_Preserve(protPtr);
            interp = protPtr->interp;
            Tcl_Preserve(interp);
            result = Tcl_EvalEx(interp, protPtr->command, -1, TCL_EVAL_GLOBAL);
            if (result != TCL_OK) {
                Tcl_AppendObjToErrorInfo(interp, Tcl_ObjPrintf(
                        "\n    (command for \"%s\" window manager protocol)",
                        protocolName));
                Tcl_BackgroundException(interp, result);
            }
            Tcl_Release(interp);
            Tcl_Release(protPtr);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (protocol == Tk_InternAtom((Tk_Window) winPtr, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW")) {
        Tk_DestroyWindow((Tk_Window) wmPtr->winPtr);
    }
}
```

Basically, Tk only really handles `_NET_WM_PING` (which it responds to for you — if you're in this handler, the event loop is running and that's what that protocol is checking for) and `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`, but it can also handle any protocol that works exactly the same as `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` *at the message level.* In particular, you've got no access to the fields of the event (except implicitly), and can't send responses to anything. That means it can handle `WM_SAVE_YOURSELF` (the old session-management protocol) but can't do `WM_TAKE_FOCUS` (and doesn't need to; Tk does its own focus management, just like every other application these days). We'd welcome an implementation of [`_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#idm45643490036528), but it's not a high priority.

## Windows

On Windows, there's some additional processing. In particular, `WM_HELP` looks like something that should be handled by [`TkTranslateWinEvent`](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/50c34e54dc3e5a32c2c712809d133b23b99f5e12/win/tkWinX.c#L842).

```c
int
TkTranslateWinEvent(
    HWND hwnd,
    UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam,
    LRESULT *resultPtr)
{
    *resultPtr = 0;
    switch (message) {
    case WM_RENDERFORMAT: {
        TkWindow *winPtr = (TkWindow *) Tk_HWNDToWindow(hwnd);

        if (winPtr) {
            TkWinClipboardRender(winPtr->dispPtr, wParam);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    case WM_RENDERALLFORMATS: {
        TkWindow *winPtr = (TkWindow *) Tk_HWNDToWindow(hwnd);

        if (winPtr && OpenClipboard(hwnd)) {
            if (GetClipboardOwner() == hwnd) {
                TkWinClipboardRender(winPtr->dispPtr, CF_TEXT);
            }
            CloseClipboard();
        }
        return 1;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    case WM_VSCROLL:
    case WM_HSCROLL: {
        HWND target = (message == WM_NOTIFY)
                ? ((NMHDR*)lParam)->hwndFrom : (HWND) lParam;

        if (target && target != hwnd) {
            *resultPtr = SendMessageW(target, message, wParam, lParam);
            return 1;
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
    case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK:
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK:
    case WM_XBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK:
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    case WM_MBUTTONUP:
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    case WM_XBUTTONUP:
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        TkWinPointerEvent(hwnd, (short) LOWORD(lParam), (short) HIWORD(lParam));
        return 1;

    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_PACKET) {
            *resultPtr =
                PostMessageW(hwnd, message, HIWORD(lParam), LOWORD(lParam));
            return 1;
        }
        /* fall through */
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_SETFOCUS:
    case WM_KILLFOCUS:
    case WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD:
    case WM_UNICHAR:
    case WM_CHAR:
    case WM_SYSKEYUP:
    case WM_KEYUP:
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    case WM_MOUSEHWHEEL:
        GenerateXEvent(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        return 1;
    case WM_MENUCHAR:
        GenerateXEvent(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        *resultPtr = MAKELONG (0, MNC_CLOSE);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't handle it. If it were to, mapping it to generate the `<KeyPress-Help>` event would probably be the right approach (yes, that's a real event, one that you never see on Windows because of the different standard keyboard layout). Which would also require changes to `GenerateXEvent` (same file, just below).

I've no idea what the `DefWindowProcW` does with `WM_HELP`; that's the function of last resort for an event in Windows, and that's definitely where those events are going at the moment.

---

Changing any of this *is* possible, but does require a little bit of C programming at a level of GUI programming that almost nobody works at. Patches can be submitted at https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktnew (I'd recommend developing against the `core-8-5-branch` *in this case,* as I think this is a small feature change that can be slipped into patches for old versions).

Comment: This is all about as low level as you ever really get in GUI toolkit programming. All this event mapping and so on is what toolkits try to hide from you because it is _boring_ and absolutely must be correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your time and effort to this detailed answer.